# Write a compact spelling checker

Tags: code-golf, string

Here is a list of [1000 basic English words](http://pastebin.com/wh6yxrqp). Yes, I'm aware that there are only 997 words in the list! It was taken from [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:1000_basic_English_words) so blame them!

Your task is to write a program that accepts a word and returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` (or `0` or `1`) depending on whether the word is in the list or not. You must use the spelling as it appears in the list, so it is `colour`, not `color` (sorry Americans!). As far as I am aware, there is only one word in the list that uses a capital letter: `I`. This means that `i` (Roman numeral for 1) should return `FALSE`. All other words may be spelt with an initial capital letter, i.e. `Colour` should return `TRUE`.

Rules for letter cases: Your program should return `TRUE` for any word that has just the first letter capitalised. If the entire word is capitalised, e.g. `COLOUR` it's your choice whether it is correct or not, as long as it is found in the word list in its lowercase form. If you accept `COLOUR` you must accept all other words entirely in capitals. If you don't accept `COLOUR` you must not accept any other word entirely in capitals. Any other mixture of lower and upper case e.g. `coLoUR` should return `FALSE`. As stated above only `I` is correct, not `i`. Briefly, both lowercase `colour` and titlecase `Colour` must be `TRUE`, uppercase `COLOUR` may be either `TRUE` or `FALSE` and any other mixed case must be `FALSE`.

Standard rules apply, you may not use external libraries or spelling libraries built into your language, etc. If you use any external files, such as reading the word list via the internet, you must include that number of bytes in your score. Reading the uncompressed word list will add 5942 to your score.

Your code must be at least 95% accurate, including both false positives and false negatives. So if you have 30 false positives and 20 false negatives there are 50 errors in total which is acceptable (even though there are only 997 words, 94.98% accurate if you're being pedantic). One more false positive or false negative invalidates your code. You must post all the errors for verification. Don't make people guess where the errors are!

Shortest code in bytes wins. Add 10 points for each error. Please post a non-golfed version of your code as well so that other people can try to break it / verify that it works. If you can provide a link to a working online version that would be great! The list is 5942 bytes long so ideally you want your code to be shorter than that.

Start your post with the following:

#### <Language> - Bytes: <num>, False +ves: <num>, False -ves: <num> = Score: <num>

Score = bytes + 10 × (false_pos + false_neg)

I might provide a list of false positives to check against as people post answers.

Comment: What is the space where false positives can come from? All strings? It's hard to count false positives if you don't know what to check.

Comment: @isaacg Assume the input is always a single word, all ASCII [A-Za-z]. I'm pretty sure there are only single words in the list, no non-alphabetic characters.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I meant what if `daskjhaasudftaigusdfasdfasdasuhdfasdfasdfasdad` happens to be accepted by the program - is that a false positive? Or is there some specific, finite list of words we can check to count false positives?

Comment: I will compile a list of specific, known false positives as the challenge progresses, i.e. "checking the word `XXX` break's Fred's code". Since this is supposed to be a spelling checker and there's nothing to stop real people from typing garbage the program should accept all garbage words and output `FALSE`. If a garbage string doesn't produce a false positive on anyone's code (or it only produces a false positive on an entry that has too many false positives anyway) that word won't be added to the list.

Comment: If `Colour` returns `TRUE`, what about `cOlOUr`?

Comment: @Sp3000 Would you accept that as correctly spelt in a book or an email? I'll go as far as `COLOUR` which is optional. That is to say `COLOUR` may produce `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on the intent of the programmer. `COLOR` must always produce `FALSE`. Any other weird capitalisation must produce `FALSE` as well. So, `colour` and `Colour` must be `TRUE`, `COLOUR` may be either `TRUE` or `FALSE` (but consistently across all words) and `color`, `Color`, `COLOR`, `CoLoUr` etc. must always produce `FALSE`.

Comment: The list only contains 997 unique words — `help` and `smoke` both appear twice

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Well done for spotting that! I'll update!

Comment: Not a duplicate, but what a [weird coincidence](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/51307/create-a-basic-spell-checker)

Comment: @trichoplax I know! I specifically checked for duplicates before writing this question and that question was posted while I was writing this one!

Comment: Re: *If a garbage string doesn't produce a false positive on anyone's code (or it only produces a false positive on an entry that has too many false positives anyway) that word won't be added to the list.* — this approach is really going to put people off submitting entries before a list appears. As things stand, my answer is the only one that will generate false positives, so your list will consist exclusively of words that my code can't handle. Seems a bit unfair...

Comment: I think the list of tests for false positives will need to be at least as large as the list of valid words. Otherwise it will be easier/shorter to encode the list of invalid words.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Anyone can invalidate your code by proving more than 50 false positives so I don't think this is a concern.

Comment: True. But then they can update their code again to exclude those. So in the end, you will still have 1000 words. Also, I have a feeling that if anybody systematically searches for false positives for a given solution, any solution that has false positives will have at least 50 of them. I doubt that solutions with false positives are viable, at least as long as somebody puts an effort into finding enough words that break them.

Comment: @CJDennis That sounds more like [tag:cops-and-robbers] than [tag:code-golf]

Comment: If it's obvious that more than 50 words will break the code they don't need to be specified individually. It's only if someone has a fuzzy solution and is running close to the wind. A few extra words might be enough to break their code.

Comment: Pastebin uses DOS line breaks, so the file they host is 6937 bytes.  You can recreate the 5942 size by converting it. (MD5 of the 5942 file is `673911d27b213a0812598bf3b6b6c9ee`)

Answer (score 3):

#### Python - Bytes: 4411, False +ves: 0, False -ves: 0 = Score: 4411

```
import base64,zlib,sys;T=eval(zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode("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")));t=T;f=1
for c in sys.argv[1]:
 C=c.lower()
 if c in t:t=t[c]
 elif f and C in t:f=0;t=t[C]
 else:t={}
print""in t
```

This is a python program that expects one command line argument, the `word`. From the list of words I constructed a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), zlib'ed the argument and finally encoded it with base64. If the word is in the trie, the program prints `True`, otherwise it prints `False`. I wanted to create a spell checker that has 100% accuracy.

I could substantially decrease the number of characters, by not encoding the zlib'ed string (specifically, zlib'ed string is 1113 characters shorter than base 64 encoded), but I wanted to have a code that you can copy/paste directly.

#### Examples

```
$python check.py colour
True

$python check.py Colour
True

$python check.py coLoUr
False

$python check.py color
False

$python check.py Color
False

$python check.py I
True

$python check.py i
False
```

The trie is traversed with characters of the `word`, each time getting a new trie from the key of current character. If the word is in the trie, then a `""` must be present in the final trie.

#### Ungolfed version

```
import base64, zlib, sys

TRIE = eval(zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode("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")))

trie = TRIE
first = True
for character in sys.argv[1]:
    CHARACTER = character.lower()
    if character in trie:
        trie = trie[character]
    elif first and CHARACTER in trie:
        first = False
        trie = trie[CHARACTER]
    else:
        print False
if "" not in trie:
    print False
print True
```

#### Construction of base 64 encoded, zlib'ed trie

```
f = file("dictionary","r")
END = ""
TRIE = {}

def addWord(word):
    trie = TRIE
    for character in word:
        trie = trie.setdefault(character, {})
    trie.setdefault(END, 0)

for line in f.readlines():
    l = line.replace("\n", "")
    addWord(l)

import zlib, base64
compressed = zlib.compress(str(TRIE).replace(" ", ""), 9)
print base64.b64encode(compressed)
```

Comment: LOL no :) ... it's a typo

Comment: Are you trying to edit your answer more times than I edited the question?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage the `else:break` would not work... If you would query with word `coloura`, which obviously is not a word, the program would return `0`. That is because in the last step, the trie would be `{"":0}`. It would not find `"a"`, but it would find `""` and return `0`.

Comment: @Nejc I deleted my comment after noticing the same thing. However, I think `else:t={};break` and `print""in t` might work. The final newline is also unnecessary

Comment: The list is also 11 bytes shorter now so you might want to recompress.

Comment: No, `print False` won't do it — "armpit" results in `False False False True`

Comment: @squeamishossifrage yes I noticed... I went for your suggestion about `t={}` I just didn't add a break, because `t={}`. It just scans the whole word until the end, even though at that point we know it won't get accepted.

Comment: You should go ahead and drop the 1113 bytes by getting rid of the base64 encoding, and add a hexdump for copy-and-pasteability.

Answer (score 2):

### PHP - Bytes : <s>2892</s> 2811, False +ves: 0, False -ves: 0 = Score: <s>2892</s> 2811

```
<?php
preg_match_all('/(\D*)(\d)/i',bzdecompress(base64_decode('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')),$b,2);$w='';foreach($b as$p){$l[]=strrev($w.=$p[1]);$w=substr($w,0,strlen($w)-$p[2]);}echo 1-!array_intersect([$argv[1],lcfirst($argv[1])],$l);
```

Ungolfed (slightly):

```
<?php
$z='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';
preg_match_all('/(\D*)(\d)/',bzdecompress(base64_decode($z)),$b,PREG_SET_ORDER);
$w='';
foreach($b as$p){
  $l[]=strrev($w.=$p[1]);
  $w=substr($w,0,strlen($w)-$p[2]);
}
echo 1-!array_intersect([$argv[1],lcfirst($argv[1])],$l);
```

#### Old data

I have applied my own compression before compressing with bzip2 and encoding as base64. My compression reduces the data from 5942 bytes to 3662 bytes, then bzip2 gets that down to 1997 bytes and base64 increases it to 2664 bytes. bzip2 without my compression gets it down to 2852.

The data used to look like this:

```
a0bout2ve4cross4t0ive1ity7dd2
```

Which translates into:

```
a
about
above
across
act
active
activity
add
```

etc. The example 29 bytes expand into 45 bytes.

#### New data

I reduced the compressed size of the data by reversing it! I saved 64 bytes in the base64 representation and only added 8 bytes to undo the reversal!

Then I just use `in_array()` to find the match in each letter case. I have chosen to save a few bytes by not checking for all uppercase words.

And, by the way, if this should somehow have the lowest score it won't be selected as the winner.

Comment: Question!  Why `print` and not `echo`?  Also, `var_dump(PREG_SET_ORDER); => 2`  ;)

Comment: @Mr.Llama Are you sure `PREG_SET_ORDER == 2` for all versons of PHP?

Comment: [Since like forever](http://3v4l.org/spAig), yes.

Answer (score 1):

#### Python 2 - Bytes: 3170, False +ves: 0, False -ves: 0 = Score: 3170

```py
i=raw_input()
print[e for e in'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'.decode('base64').decode('zlib').split()if e[:2]==i[:1].lower()+i[1:2]and i[2:]in e[2:].split('{')]>[]or'I'==i
```

The word is taken from standard input, and `True` or `False` is printed in response. The code part isn't very golfed yet. Here's a (somewhat) more readable version:

```py
i = raw_input()
d = 'eJw1lwF64yoMhK+iqxGbOGww+ ...'
d = d.decode('base64').decode('zlib').split()
m = [e for e in d if e[:2] == i[:1].lower() + i[1:2] and i[2:] in e[2:].split('{')]
print m > [] or i == 'I'
```

---

After decoding, the long string looks like this:

```
about{ove across{t{tive{tivity add afraid{ter again{e{o{ree ...
```

The words are grouped by their first two letters (i.e. `about{ove` stores `about` and `above`).

We search through each group, checking to see if any starts with the same prefix as the input word and also contains the rest of the word. Single letter words (`a`, `A` and `I`) are handled separately.

Comment: Can you save a few bytes by not including `a` and `A`? Only `I` is a special case.

Comment: @CJDennis yeah it seems to work if I move `a` in with the other words.

Answer (score 1):

**Factor - Bytes: 1342, False +ves: X, False -ves: 0 = Score: X**

```
USING: ascii base64 bit-arrays bloom-filters io kernel sequences system ;
IN: examples.golf.wordcheck

CONSTANT: S "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"

: F ( -- f )
    4 S base64> 6247 swap bit-array boa 1000 996 bloom-filter boa ;

readln 1 cut swap >lower prepend
dup "I" = [ drop t ] [ F bloom-filter-member? ] if
1 0 ? exit
```

Run using:

```
$ factor golf/wordlist/wordcheck.factor ; echo $?
color
0
$
```

The approach is based on a pre-calculated Bloom filter. There are a bunch of false positives (misspelled words seen as correctly spelled) so the code probably isn't competitive when you take that into account.

Comment: Is there an easy way I can run this code?

Comment: You need the Factor system installed (www.factorcode.org) then you can run it.

Comment: I'm interested to try and find collisions. From what I've read it should be possible to find any number if the data is long enough. If the likelihood of 50 false positives requires the data to be over 100 characters long I'll accept your answer as valid. If 50 false positives can be found in words of length up to 10 then the answer will have to be invalid. If your answer is valid the maximum penalty is 500 so you'd be the current leader! Either way, thank you for posting it! I'd never heard of Bloom filters before! Do you know how many hashes are used?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. For a random string with length < 10 the error rate is about 15%. It can be remedied with a larger filter but even with an error rate of 0.001%, it's a huge number of strings. It believe it works better for "normal" misspellings such as `colect` or `collekt`.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist There are 3,268,647,867,246,256,383,381,332,100,041,691,484,373,976,788,312,974,266,629,140,102,414,955,744,756,908,184,404,049,903,032,490,380,904,202,638,084,876,187,965,749,304,595,652,472,250,353 words of up to 100 characters that are not in the list. Your code is invalid unless it can reject at least 3,268,647,867,246,256,383,381,332,100,041,691,484,373,976,788,312,974,266,629,140,102,414,955,744,756,908,184,404,049,903,032,490,380,904,202,638,084,876,187,965,749,304,595,652,472,250,303 of them. Good luck with that. (I suggest you turn your attention to another question.)

Comment: Rough calculation: 15% of 26^2 = ~101. If this is the case 101 of all two letter lowercase combinations will give false positives, so your code is definitely not valid! I do like it, though, so please leave it up!

Comment: @CJDennis There is no point in counting false positives if the number of words that has to be rejected is many times greater than the number of particles in the universe. Please revise your question to stipulate that no false positives will be accepted, or come up with a list of non-words as you originally said you would.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage If someone can come up with a fuzzy solution that is smaller than the current responses including the penalty for having false positives then they deserve to win, as long as it can be proved that there are fewer than 50 total errors. Some solutions already have false negatives so I don't see why I should allow one but not the other. The list of non-words will be based on what people post and so far there is no valid program that produces any false positives.

Comment: Bravo on thinking of a [probabilistic data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Probabilistic_data_structures)! A [bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) or [quotient filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_filter) is a great tool for this kind of problem (they guarantee 0 FNs but will have a bunch of FPs).  It'd really become a question of how frequent the FPs are versus the saved space from the data storage (unless, as @squeamishossifrage notes, the test is 100% comprehensive … which would take centuries to run).  Try FAILing words over 9 characters.

Answer (score 1):

## Python - Bytes: 2294, False +ves: 0, False -ves: 1 = Score: 2304

Code (273 bytes):

```
import gzip
c=gzip.open("b").read()
def d(k):
 t={}
 while 1:
  b=ord(c[k]);s,k=(0,k+1)if b&32 else d(k+1);t[chr((b&31)+96)]=b&64,s;
  if b&128:break
 return t,k
t=d(0)[0]
w=raw_input()
if w.istitle():w=w.lower()
r=0
for x in w:
 r,t=t[x]if t and x in t else(0,0)
print r>0
```

In addition, this needs a binary file named `b` that is 2021 bytes long. Not sure how I can best share it. Suggestions are welcome if somebody wants to see it. Or I can post the code that produces it from the dictionary.

I'm taking a penalty for a false negative on **I**. Bothering with upper case letters, or special casing it, would cost me at least 10 bytes anyway.

The pre-processing procedure is:

- A trie is built from the 996 words in the dictionary (skipping **I**).
- The trie is encoded in a byte array. In addition to the 5 bits for the letter itself in each node, 3 extra bits are used to encode trie structure information:

  - 1 bit for tracking if the node is a leaf node.
  - 1 bit for tracking if the node is at the end of a valid word (note that non-leaf nodes can be at the end of a word, e.g. for "any" vs. "anyone").
  - 1 bit for tracking if the node is the last one in the list of children for its parent.

  The encoded byte array is 2664 bytes long.
- The encoded byte array is compressed to 2021 bytes with gzip.

The spelling check code posted here then:

- Reads the compressed and encoded trie from the binary file, and decompresses it.
- The function `d()` decodes the byte stream, and builds a trie using nested dictionaries.
- Processes the input word for the upper/lower case rules (all upper is not accepted).
- Walks the trie letter by letter until either the end of the input word is reached, or a leaf node of the trie.
- Prints the result.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript <del>4737</del> 4378

```js
alert(is(prompt("enter word")))
function is(w){if(w=="I")return true;w=w.toLowerCase();var key='/345I_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',x = "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"
for(var i=0,t="",x=atob(x),m;i<x.length;i++)m=x.charCodeAt(i).toString(2),t+="00000000".substr(m.length)+m
t=t.replace(/.{5}/g, function(m){return key.charAt(parseInt(m,2))}).split(/_/)[0];
t=JSON.parse("{"+t.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g,'"$&":{').replace(/\/(\d*)/g, function(m,d){
for(var n=parseInt(d,10)||1,o="";n--;)o+="}"
return o +",";}).replace(/\,\}/g, "}").replace(/\{\,/g, "{").replace(/\,$/, "").replace(/\{\}/g, "null"))
for(var i=0,n=t,c;i<w.length;n=n[c]){
c=w.charAt(i++)
if(!(c in n))return false}
return n==null}
```

There's three encodings of the words. First the words are converted into a shorthand tree like `about/2ve`. This has the word **about** then back 2 `/2` add `ve` for **above**.  The encoding is converted to only allow for / /3 /4 and /5 backing and all others are converted as combinations.  This gives a total of 32 different chars and allows for 5 bit encoding.  The 5bit encoding is binary and needs to be base64 encoded.

When decoding the shorthand tree is converted to a JSON tree for a simple node search.

I initially tried to use canvas and toDataURL to get some compression but it wasn't good. If you go that route do not use the alpha channel. Browsers hack the alpha and do rounding with the data so just set that to 255 and put your data in rgb.

Comment: Capitalised words seem to return false...

Comment: @Tobsta thanks. I fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

### Shell - Bytes: 2545, False +ves: 0, False -ves: 0 = Score: 2545

Code: <s>54</s> 52 bytes, Dictionary: <s>2518</s> <s>2494</s> 2493 bytes, FP: <s>1</s> 0, FN: 0

```bash
[ $1 = "${1#?*[A-Z]}" ]&&unlzma<z|grep -qix "${1%I}"
```

Quotes are not needed around the initial `$1` because "[the input is always a single word, all ASCII `[A-Za-z]`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/51308/write-a-compact-spelling-checker#comment121754_51308)."  However, quotes *are* needed around the parameter expansions because they might generate an empty string.

#### Examples:

In shell, an exit code of `0` is true (anything else is false).  `$?` is the previous command's exit code.

```bash
$ sh in997 colour; echo $?
0
$ sh in997 Colour; echo $?
0
$ sh in997 coLoUr; echo $?
1
$ sh in997 COLOUR; echo $?  # I chose to consistently mark these false
1
$ sh in997 Color; echo $?
1
$ sh in997 I; echo $?
0
$ sh in997 i; echo $?
1
$ sh in997 ColourI; echo $? # testing because I strip off one trailing "I"
1
$ sh in997 II; echo $?      # … and "I" isn't in the dictionary (see below)
1
```

(Examples copied from [Nejc's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/51308/write-a-compact-spelling-checker#51318) plus an all-caps example and two tests for specific corner cases used to vet my `i` vs `I` logic.  I have no idea why Google Prettify likes Proper Case and CamelCase words when highlighting `lang-bash`.)

#### Ungolfed and explained:

```bash
if [ "$1" = "${1#?*[A-Z]}" ]; then
  cat z | unlzma | grep -q -i -x "${1%I}"
fi
```

The conditional compares the argument with itself after a string manipulation that alters the string if it matches any character followed by any number of characters followed by an uppercase letter (equivalent to `s/^..*?[A-Z]//` – ignore the [`?`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy) if you don't understand it), which would compare `coLoUr` to `oUr` and `Colour` to `Colour`.  This controls for mixed case (and fails all-caps), though it skips the first letter. It accepts `i` (but neither `i` nor `I` are in the dictionary, see below).

If the conditional matches (there are no capitals after the first letter), `unlzma` is run on the contents of the file named `z`, which puts the uncompressed dictionary into standard output.  `grep` then queries quietly (`-q`), without regard to case—we've already controlled for that (`-i`), and on a whole line (`-x`).

The query is an altered version of the argument: if the argument has a trailing capital `I` (case sensitive!), it is removed.  Because we controlled for case earlier, the only time we'd remove a capital `I` would be for the word `I`, in which case the `grep` query seeks an empty string on its own line.  The dictionary's `I` entry was swapped for a blank line, so we'll get a match.

The last item that executed dictates the exit value of the script.  If the conditional was false, the script exits false.  If `grep` found no match, it (and the script) return false.  If `grep` found a match, it and the script return true.

#### Dictionary creation:

Wow.  There are some awesome dictionary compression schemes in other answers here.  I didn't do anything that fancy.  There is zero custom compression in this code (unless you count removing DOS linebreaks), just minor prep work that makes it easier to check later on (blanking the `I` line actually *costs* a byte!).

I just took the stock dictionary, blanked the `I`, and compressed the output.  I chose [LZMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Markov_chain_algorithm) because it compressed this particular file better than `zip`, `gzip`, `bzip2`, `xz`, or `zlib`.

Here's my code:

```bash
wget -qqO- 'http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=wh6yxrqp' \
  | perl -pne 's/\r//; s/^I$//' | lzma -c9 > z
```

`wget` flags `-qqO-` suppress all output and sends the HTML content to standard output.  That's parsed by `perl`, which removes the DOS line breaks (`\r`) and converts the `I` entry to a blank line (since we stripped the trailing `I` in `grep`).  That's then passed to `lzma` which outputs the compressed dictionary into a pipe to file `z`.

Note that `unlzma` will refuse to operate on a file lacking the `.lzma` extension, but it's fine with a pipeline.  That means `unlzma z` fails while `unlzma<z` (effectively `cat z | unlzma`) succeeds.

Comment: If you're curious, my dictionary would be 834 bytes larger if it were base64-encoded.  That (plus the 10 bytes from adding `|base64 -d`) would easily remove my answer from the leaders' pack, whereas LZMA could radically improve other answers here.